# Base64 error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have downloaded org.apache.commons.codec (1.9) and imported the jar files into my project added the import declaration but am getting an error!

Is the error in my code or have I not correctly imported the jar?

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

[image: Error in eclipse]

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `org.apache.commons.codec (1.9)` `Base64` class does not have any `static` method named `encodeBytes`

See the full documentation [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.9/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html)

These are the methods available to `encode/decode` from the above link:

```
decodeBase64(byte[] base64Data)
decodeBase64(String base64String)
decodeInteger(byte[] pArray)
encodeBase64(byte[] binaryData)
encodeBase64(byte[] binaryData, boolean isChunked)
encodeBase64(byte[] binaryData, boolean isChunked, boolean urlSafe)
encodeBase64(byte[] binaryData, boolean isChunked, boolean urlSafe, int maxResultSize)
encodeBase64Chunked(byte[] binaryData)
encodeBase64String(byte[] binaryData)
encodeBase64URLSafe(byte[] binaryData)
encodeBase64URLSafeString(byte[] binaryData)
```

You may want to review your usage and pick the relevant method for your usage.

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.9 of the `Base64` doesn't have an `encodeBytes` method [according to the Javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.9/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html). I guess what you're looking for is [`Base64.encodeBase64String(byte[])`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.9/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64String%28byte%5B%5D%29).